# Firebase Crashlytics: Same app sending to different firebase projetcs

Tags: firebase, crashlytics

I have apps which uses a library I've created.

I want to have a project for the lib and on for each firebase projects, one for the app, other for the lib, and send the crashes for both projects.

**Why?** There are several apps that uses the same library, and they send crash reports only to its respective project. I want all of them to send the reports to a central project, so I can see the crashes caused by the lib in a central place.

Please let me know if I was clear!

Comment: Think that one can only register apps. not libraries.

Comment: Crashlytics only collects crashes for entire individual apps, not individual libraries used in many apps.